# How to copy and rename file to output folder as part of build

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild

I believe this is more of an msbuild-related question.
Have a .net core app and I need to conditionally publish a file and based on the build config selected in Visual Studio 2019, the file should be renamed before publishing to the target.

So Im looking at modifying the csproj file (which is nothing but an msbuild file itself)
I dont see a condition option on the copy task
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/copy-task?view=vs-2019

The goal Im after, is if I have 3 different files
tester-notes.dev.json
tester-notes.debug.json
tester-notes.prod.json

If prod is selected as a build config, I want the file published to be tester-notes.prod.json, but renamed to tester-notes.json

Comment: When do you get those three files, before the build or after the build? (The build generates those files?)

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you have three files(build action = None) in Solution Explorer when developing:

[image]

You can use something similar to this script to rename and copy to publish folder if you're using `FileSystem` publish mode:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="$(Configuration)=='Dev'">
    <FileToRename Include="$(ProjectDir)\tester-notes.dev.json" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="$(Configuration)=='Debug'">
    <FileToRename Include="$(ProjectDir)\tester-notes.debug.json" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="$(Configuration)=='Prof'">
    <FileToRename Include="$(ProjectDir)\tester-notes.prof.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="DoSthAfterPublish1" AfterTargets="Publish" Condition="$(Configuration)=='Dev'">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(FileToRename)" DestinationFiles="@(FileToRename->Replace('.dev.json','.json'))"/>
    <Move SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)\tester-notes.json" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true"/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="DoSthAfterPublish2" AfterTargets="Publish" Condition="$(Configuration)=='Debug'">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(FileToRename)" DestinationFiles="@(FileToRename->Replace('.debug.json','.json'))"/>
    <Move SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)\tester-notes.json" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true"/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="DoSthAfterPublish3" AfterTargets="Publish" Condition="$(Configuration)=='Prof'">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(FileToRename)" DestinationFiles="@(FileToRename->Replace('.prof.json','.json'))"/>
    <Move SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)\tester-notes.json" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true"/>
  </Target>
```

And if you can reset `tester-notes.debug.json` to `tester-notes.Debug.json`,, then we may combine the three targets into one by using `DestinationFiles="@(FileToRename->Replace('.$(Configuration).json','.json'))"`. Hope it makes some help :)

**In addition:**

According to the Intellisense we can find the `Copy task` supports `Condition`:

[image]

Comment: Cool answer, Lance! but in my case, I would like to copy it to the output folder. I'm not user the Publish feature. I hope you can shed some light here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/115938624?noredirect=1