# msbuild task that works from publish profile to remove specific file

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Have 3 json files in my project.  For a specific publish profile, using a FileSystem publish and I'm trying to find a way to have a specific file NOT be published to the target folder.  This is for a .net core console app.

This is my publish profile, but the file Im trying to restrict from being published is still published to the target folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishDir>D:\projects\test_publish</PublishDir>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>false</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>appsettings.Test.json</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Note: project file includes these files so they will be in the build output.  Might this prevent the appsettings.Test.json from being deleted and hence still get copied over to the publish dir?

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="appsettings.Local.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="appsettings.Test.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

The work-around solution I have come up with is similar to another project I have.  It involves taping into the build system and add some extra bits into the csproj file.

So the csproj file would now look like this.  It eliminates the file you dont need, and you only need to add a corresponding build config entry and this uses the VS build system to determine which of these json file(s) get output.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="appsettings.Local.json" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' " >
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="appsettings.Test.json" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Test' " >
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Hi friend, thanks for sharing your workaround and please feel free to [accept it as self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information! And maybe this workaround also works for [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58561928/how-to-copy-and-rename-file-to-output-folder-as-part-of-build)?It's just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

> This is my publish profile, but the file Im trying to restrict from
>   being published is still published to the target folder.

I test it in my local machine and reproduce same issue. Also I find if I use [this element in web application](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/web-deployment-excluding-files-and-folders-via-the-web-applications-project-file/) like asp.net, it always works. So I assume this element is not supported for publishing .net core console application.

What role does that file play in your project?

1.If your application don't need it in `build output directory` and `publish directory`, you can set the `Copy to Output Directory` to `Do not copy`.

And then clean your publish folder and publish again to check if it helps.

[image]

2.And if you have specific reason that you need the file in build, but need to exclude it from publish folder, trying adding this script into your `xx.csproj`([Delete Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/delete-task?view=vs-2019)):

```
  <Target Name="CustomTarget" AfterTargets="_PublishNoBuildAlternative">
    <Delete Files="$(PublishDir)\appsettings.Test.json"/>
    <!--<Delete Files="$(PublishDir)\appsettings.xxx.json"/>-->
  </Target>
```

You can add [MSbuild Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions?view=vs-2019) like `Condition="$(Configuration)=='xxx'"` to the targets to make it more flexible.

Comment: That is the issue, I do need it in a build, in the case I am running locally and set my environment to 'Test'.  However, to your suggestion #2, that doesnt seem to work, as appsettings.Test.json is still in the publish dir and yes I did clean out my publish folder (actually just deleted the bin & obj folders) and re-ran the publish.

Comment: @bitshift My fault... Just update the answer, the `_PublishNoBuildAlternative` target should be the working one for .net core console instead of Publish Target.  Please test it by publishing in VS IDE, if you're running it by command-line and it not works there, please let me know that :)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work either, yes publishing through VS 2019 (community edition).  Have VS Pro at the office, will try that in a bit. See also edit above.

Comment: Just tested this in VS pro, doesnt work there either, in addition to VS Community edition.  So it appears at least for console apps, this isn's supported.  Maybe Ill post this as a issue over on the .net core Github

Comment: Not sure this doesn't work for your project, maybe you can set the build verbosity to Detailed to see more details. Anyway, glad to know you've found the workaround which works in your machine :) Please consider accepting it as self-answer to share the useful info to others after the [limit of two days](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) ...